# Unable to find the driver com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource register this driver in the databases tab

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un pool de conexiones en un servidor weblogic 12C, la conexión y la inserción de datos a la base de datos mapeando las clases de forma manual se realiza de forma normal, el problema se da cuando intento hacerla con New Entity Classes from database en netbeans 8.1 me arroja el siguiente error:

```
unable to find the driver com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource register this driver in the databases tab
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sucede que debes cargar la librería de conexión a base de datos dentro de las librerías comunes de tu servidor de aplicaciones. En este caso, la librería que debes colocar es [mysql-connector-j](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html).

De acuerdo a [la documentación oficial de WebLogic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24367/third_party_drivers.htm#JDBCA233), debes colocar la librería en la siguiente ruta:

> WL_HOME\server\lib

Donde `WL_HOME` es la carpeta de instalación de tu servidor WebLogic.

---

Al parecer, WebLogic tiene su propio jar de conexión a MySQL. Quizás debas averiguar cuál es la clase que te permite crear conexiones en dicho jar y debas configurar esa clase en tu pool de conexiones en lugar de utilizar la clase `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource`.

Comment: Ok gracias por la respuesta ya agrego la librería.